# How to reproject .nc file to a new .nc file

Tags: equal-earth-projection

I download some vegetation cover data from "https://dap.nci.org.au/thredds/remoteCatalogService?catalog=http://dapds00.nci.org.au/thredds/catalog/tc43/modis-fc/v310/tiles/monthly/catalog.xml".

here are some information about my data:

```
gridtype  = projection

gridsize  = 5760000

xsize     = 2400

ysize     = 2400

xname     = x

xlongname = "x coordinate of projection"

xunits    = "m"

yname     = y

ylongname = "y coordinate of projection"

yunits    = "m"

xfirst    = 231.656358264

xinc      = 463.312716528

yfirst    = 6671471.46164174

yinc      = -463.312716528

grid_mapping = sinusoidal

grid_mapping_name = sinusoidal

false_easting = 0.

false_northing = 0.

longitude_of_central_meridian = 0.

longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.

semi_major_axis = 6371007.181

inverse_flattening = 0.

spatial_ref = 'PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["Unknown datum based upon the custom 
spheroid",DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid",SPHEROID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]'

GeoTransform = "0.0 463.312716528 0.0 6671703.118 0.0 -463.312716528 "
```

I want to reproject it to WGS84. How to realise it using Gdal.
I used gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -of netCDF input.nc output_reprojected.nc It not working.

It cannot find " libgeos_c.so.1:". Then I added another module "geos", it works

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I do not make it clear. It cannot find " libgeos_c.so.1:". Then I added another module "geos", it works. Do you know how to make the same resolution after re-projection?   I have two tiles of MODIS data with sinusoidal projection. After gdalwarp, the resolutions of the two files are different. Or what if I combine the two tiles before re-projection, CDO can not do the combination, is there any methods in Gdal? Thanks!!